# Bash PS1 prompt setting \h strips the hostname after the first dot

Tags: bash

My system hostname is like this: `192.168.2.1_machine05` and my bash prompt `$PS1` setting is `[\u@\h \W]\$`.

Since there is a dot character in the hostname, the `\h` variable extracts only the first portion of the string that comes before the first dot character and rest of the characters that follows the first dot are ignored.

To avoid it I have to use: `PS1='[\u@$(uname -n) \W]\$ '`

Can I make this `\h` variable show the complete hostname?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions "*unique to software development*". Writing scripts in bash is generally on-topic here, but configuring your interactive shell environment is relevant to non-developers as well, and is thus a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to bash [manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html) (in section `PROMPTING`):

```
\h     the hostname up to the first `.'
\H     the hostname
```